# You're born with it

Tags: riddle

This is a riddle my aunt has translated to me from French several years ago:

> It's greater than God and worse than Satan,
>   poor people have plenty of it and rich lack it,
>   you're born with it but if you eat it, you will die.

What is it?

Comment: @Wu33o This is the last time I used SO search instead to google search when looking for duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Nothing

It's greater than God

> Nothing is greater than god

worse than Satan

> Nothing is worse than Satan

poor people have plenty of it and rich lack it

> Poor people have nothing , rich people need nothing

you're born with it but if you eat it, you will die

> We are born with nothing, and if we eat "nothing" , you will die

Answer (score 2):

Too old, but the answer is

> "Nothing".
>
>  Nothing is greater than God or worse than Satan, Poor people have nothing, rich lack nothing, You're born with nothing, if you eat nothing you will die!

Comment: Welcome to puzzling SE. Please consider using spoiler while answering from next time.

Comment: Thanks, could not seem to find the spoiler tag when answering. Can I know what it is?

Comment: You need to use >! before the text that you don't want to spoil for others.